# How can I access the public array in this class

Tags: java

```
package bagimplementation.ch1;
import bagimplementation.Bag;
import bagimplementation.BagInterface;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * A class that implements a piggy bank by using a bag.
 * @author Jeff Nicholas
 */
public class PiggyBank {
    private BagInterface<Coin> coins;
    public static String[] coinsArray;
    public PiggyBank(){
        coins = new Bag<Coin>();
    }

    public boolean add(Coin aCoin){
        return coins.add(aCoin);
    }

    public Coin remove(){
        return coins.remove();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return coins.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

What I want to do is call the variable  *coinsArray* within the test class which has the main method. I added a print statement to the test class to see if I have any data added to the array but the printout is null, so it has no data. The test class follows

```
public class PiggyBankExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PiggyBank myBank = new PiggyBank();

        addCoin(new Coin(1, 2010), myBank);
        addCoin(new Coin(5, 2011), myBank);
        addCoin(new Coin(10, 2000), myBank);
        addCoin(new Coin(25, 2012), myBank);

        System.out.println((PiggyBank.coinsArray));
        System.out.println("Removing all the coins:");
        int amountRemoved = 0;

        while(!myBank.isEmpty()){
            Coin removedCoin = myBank.remove();

            System.out.println("Removed a " + removedCoin.getCoinName() + 
                               ".");
            amountRemoved += removedCoin.getCoin();
        }

        System.out.println("All done. Removed " + amountRemoved + " cents.");
    }

    private static void addCoin(Coin aCoin, PiggyBank aBank){
        if(aBank.add(aCoin)){
            System.out.println("Added a " + aCoin.getCoinName() + ".");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Tried to add a " + aCoin.getCoinName() +
                               ", but couldn't");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: That array shouldn't be public, and it **definitely** shouldn't be static.

Comment: I should have pointed out that I realize the data within the myBank variable is of int type, and the coinsArray is String type. I've tried unsuccessfully to cast myBank to String type into coinsArray as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's because coinsArray is never changed in your code. You are only changing the *coins* variable in the object.

Have you tried adding a proxy method on PiggyBank to access the toArray method of Bag ?

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return coins.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Let's say I remove the print statement to print coinsArray in the test class. The PiggyBank class is a Bag object. The BagInterface interface has a toArray method. Can you tell my why I'm not able to use the myBank object to the toArray() method to create an array?

Comment: Probably because you call the toArray on the wrong object. See the edit.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the following output if I attempt to print the contents of the array:
bagimplementation.ch1.PiggyBank@15db9742

I'm trying to get the contents of myBank to print out. At this point I'm sure that there is a rule I'm missing, but can't remember what is causing it.

Comment: I've tried the following aside from just calling the toArray() method within the test class on the myBank variable. 
After calling the toArray() method on myBank I tried 
List bankList = Arrays.asList(myBank);
System.out.println(bankList);
I end up with the same output